# Adding method to a golang struct in a different file

Tags: go, methods, struct

How would one go about adding a method to a struct that is a different file?
This is what I've tried so far but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
// ./src
package routes

type App struct{

}

func (a *App) initializeRoutes() {
  a.Subrouter.HandleFunc("/products", a.getSomething).Methods("GET")
}
```

---

```
// ./src/controller
package routes

func (a *App) getSomething(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

...

}
```

Comment: v.Subrouter.HandleFunc( ... should be a.Subrouter.Handle...

Comment: I'm new, but I'm wondering if it would make a difference whether they are part of the same package.  Are they?

Comment: That's the key factor. It doesn't matter if they're in different files, but you can't add methods to a type defined in a different package.

Comment: They are in the same package.

Answer (score 26):

> *They are in the same package.*

They are not in the same package. A Go package has both a name and a path. They're both named `routes` but they have different paths. The actual packages are `routes` and `controller/routes`. The result is subdirectories are different packages.

See [Package Names on the Go Blog](https://blog.golang.org/package-names) for more information.

Since they're in different packages, they can only access each other's public members and exported methods. You can't monkey patch someone else's package or interface in Go. This is by design to keep all the functionality of a package in one place, no action-at-a-distance.

You have options. You could put all methods of `routes` into a single package. If they all belong together, there's no need to split it up into multiple files.

If they don't really belong together, you can write a new struct with routes embedded into it and define new methods on that. Then you can access either the wrapper struct to get your added methods, or its embedded struct to get `routes`' methods. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45019509/14660) for an example.

---

But really I think you need to think about how your code is arranged. The `App` probably shouldn't be defined by the `routes` package, they should be separate. Instead, Go prefers a has-a relationship. `App` would contain an instance of `routes.Route`.

You'd rearrange your code tree like so:

```
app/
    app.go
    app_test.go
    routes/
        routes.go
        routes_test.go
```

Note that rather than having it all in `src/` it's now contained in its own project directory. `app.go` would look something like this.

```
// src/app/app.go
package app

import(
    "app/routes"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type App struct {
    routes routes.Route
}

func (a *App) initializeRoutes() {
    a.routes.AddRoute("/products", a.getSomething)
}

func (a *App) getSomething(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Something!")
}
```

Notice how we're delegating responsibility to adding a route to `a.routes` rather than having `App` do it itself. This avoids the desire to smash all functionality into one ginormous package. `routes.Route` would be defined in `app/routes/routes.go`.

```
// src/app/routes/routes.go
package routes

import "net/http"

// A type specifying the interface for route handlers.
type RouteHandler func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)

type Route struct {
    handlers map[string]RouteHandler
}

func (r *Route) AddRoute(path string, handler RouteHandler) {
    r.handlers[path] = handler
}
```

Now all routes has to worry about is handling routes. It doesn't know anything about your specific application logic.

---

> *I was trying to get my http.res & http.req functions in a controllers file.*

Now that we've rearranged the file structure, you can do that. You can, if you like, define `app/controllers.go` to organize your code.

```
// src/app/controllers.go
package app

import(
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func (a *App) getSomething(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Something!")
}
```

`app/app.go` and `app/controllers.go` are in the same package. They have the same path and the same name. So `app/controllers.go` can add methods to `App`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. I was trying to get all of my handler's in a controller folder relative to their feature.

Comment: @JosephPalacio I've added an example of how you can put the handlers in their own file for organizational purposes.

Comment: Thank you! This really helps a lot.

Comment: You should mark this as answer. It is very well explained and detailed.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error because your files belong to different packages. Everything related to one struct must be in the same package.
It is possible to declare struct and its methods in different files, but they must belong same package (be in same folder).

Comment: They are in the same package. package routes, I'm still getting the error.
app/routes/v1/index.go:47: v.getProducts undefined (type *V1 has no field or method getProducts)

Comment: Please take a closer look at <bold>(be in same folder)</bold>

Comment: oh. I see that now